# Installing phpmyadmin package ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, packages, phpmyadmin

I need to create a new mySQL db for a local site, I thought I'd do that with phpMyAdmin so I installed that package like so:

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

During this process I get a couple of prompts and one of them is:

```
The phpmyadmin package must have a database installed and configured before it can be used.
This can be optionally handled with dbconfig-common.
```

I decide to go with the dbconfig-common.

I'm then asked to provide the password for administrative account to create the MySQL db/user:

`Password of the database's administrative user:`

Is this the sudo password? I assumed I was *setting* a password, so I write my new password.

```
An error occurred while installing the database:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

After I get this error, I'm offered to retry and i do that with various passwords, whatever I choose puts me back to this prompt.

The research I've made doesn't explain what is expected here but rather suggests to revise config files. Any ideas?

---

- OS: `Ubuntu 13.10`
- MySQL: `5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Password of the database's administrative user* is NOT the root password. You may don't have `MySQL` installed. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

You'll be asked for a password. This is the password that you'll have to use.

Then, re-install `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 1):

Either your permissions arent set correctly for root or you've forgotten the mysql root password.
As your linux root password most likely is(or atleast shouldnt be) not the same.

to reset your mysql root password follow the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset